# Indian English gesture typing keyboard for Android KitKat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, keyboard, gboard, gesture-typing

Switched from Windows 8.1 to Android KitKat recently. Windows 8.1 keyboard had the option of gesture typing for Hindi words written in English script.
For example, "bhag" (means *run* in English) could be typed in via gestures.
 Something which they called the **Indian English keyboard**.

Does Android KitKat have an Indian English **gesture** keyboard? If yes, then how can I enable it?

There are some apps in play store which does the same, however I would like this feature in the default Google keyboard itself.

Comment: Download English(Indian) or Hinglish languages for **Google keyboard** in **Language and Input settings**. Comment if not worked.

Comment: @MANI Indian English is already selected as the language option on my phone.... Its dictionary seems pretty weak... Only a few very common words are recognized... Maybe that's because I haven't updated the keyboard

Comment: Okay update the keyboard first. Updates are also available for language too

Comment: @MANI one more thing... English (India) is selected as the language option... And in keyboard language I selected "use system language"... However this automatically selects English (US) as the keyboard input language... Is this the problem?

Comment: @MANI can you please suggest how to check for language updates?

Comment: Yes change it to English(in) and updates are shown below languages installed.

Comment: @MANI updated the Google keyboard and set both language and input options to English (India)... But still no luck with Hindi words

Comment: @MANI downloaded the "Google Hindi input keyboard" from app store... This enables a "Hinglish" keyboard option which has all the Hindi words as well as an amazing feature of converting Hinglish text directly to Devanagari... Still no gesture typing :'(

Comment: I'll get back to you if I find a solution.